# How to conduct a power analysis for a linear regression with clustered standard errors?

Tags: r, statistical-power, clustered-standard-errors, robust-standard-error

I would like to conduct a posthoc power analysis for a linear regression model to see the power of my analysis given the effect size I am finding. However, due to the clustering of standard errors, I do have many variables (mostly dummies) in my model. Is there a way around it? Do I have to include cluster dummies in my power analysis?

I am using the R code below to define my models. The model consists of a continuous criterion (market returns), and IV (sentiment in press statements), two financial indicators as moderators and a set of controls. It is all part of an event study on firm market returns upon acquisition announcement.

```
reg_2_formula <- as.formula(paste(DV, "~", 
                                  paste(IV, moderator_A, moderator_B, controls,
                                        sep = "+")))

reg_2 <- lm(reg_2_formula,
            data = model_data_centered])

m2coeffs_cl <- coeftest(reg_2, vcov = vcovCL, cluster = ~CUSIP_6dig)
m2coeffs_std <- data.frame(summary(reg_2)$coefficients)
coi_indices <- which(!startsWith(row.names(m2coeffs_std), 'CUSIP_6dig'))
m2coeffs_cl[coi_indices,]
```

I am using the sandwich package to calculate robust standard errors and cluster them by firm ID (here: a six-digit CUSIP code). Since I have many firms in my data, I end up with a total variable count of 277 on a sample of roughly 1500 observations.

Again my questions. Do I have to include cluster variables (dummies) in my power analysis? Is there a more elegant way of handling these dummies in my power analysis?